# Java JOptionPane default text

Tags: java, default, joptionpane

When I ask a user to enter a quantity for a program I have made using the code below, the default text is 3.

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter new quantity",
                                           JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

How do I change this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the default text"?

Comment: The text in the text field which is already entered

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) you have used is:

```
public static String showInputDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                     Object message,
                                     Object initialSelectionValue)
```

Here 3rd argument (`initialSelectionValue`) is default value in text field. You gave `JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE` as 3rd argument which is an int constant having value = 3. So you get 3 as a default value entered in text field.

Try this:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please enter new quantity", "");
```

or this

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please enter new quantity", "Please enter new quantity",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: `String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please enter new quantity", "Please enter new quantity",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,null,"default text").toString;`

Comment: ^^ I think that should be voted as the best answer to this question as it allows for a title also .But for some reason it gives me an error.

Comment: The reason for NullPointer exception is that you are using `toString()` on the resulting object of `JOptionPane`. You first need to check that the object is not null, and then use `toString()` after. @Neifen 's comment will have null pointer exception if the entry in the input dialog is blank.

Answer (score 12):

This way it will work:

```
String input = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter new quantity",
"Please enter new quantity", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,null,"default text");
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using is [JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component, Object, Object)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)).

The method you want to use is [JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component, Object, String, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int)).

Comment: I want the user to be able to enter a number when I did this JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter new quantity", "Please enter new quantity", 1) It just displayed a pop up with no input box, am I doing something wrong???

Comment: @Ste T You will be able to. Change your method call to `String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter new quantity", "Title", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)`;

Comment: Please check your links as they appear in the 'preview' in future, and note that it is best to link to the JavaDocs of the current version (adding '6' to the search for `ClassName+javadoc+6` should do it).